# Something breaking my site in IE

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, modernizr

I been scratching my head for a long time now :/

My site is breaking in Internet Explorer: http://www.tolux.se/

It's built on boilerplate and wordpress.

Been trying to figure out whats breaking the site in IE...
When I do all the css and html everything is fine. Then I make it to a wordpress theme. Everything is still fine in IE. I activate three plugins: formidable, custom post type ui and simple fields. Everything seems fine, then i start working with some content etc, thinking everything is ok now, but no. I been doing this over and over, removing code, plugins everything back and forth but cant figure out what breaks the site :(

Maby something with the modernizr?

I really need some help here. Been trying for hours and hours now. Think i built the site from scratch four times. lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a doctype, but there is white space above it with invisible characters that are throwing off IE. And, your text files need to be Unicode No BOM. (Byte Order Mark)

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   tolux.se  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.tolux.se/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had missed to change to UTF in one file................ I learned something new today........ I put down 5x time on this site for no reason :/ Now I know better to validate with W3C! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a valid DOCTYPE, or IE defaults to quirks mode and won't render many things correctly.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` works if you're using HTLML5 standards.

Comment: I have specified doctype, but when i look at "view source" there is two lines at the top before doctype, does that matter? And if it does, why do they get there :/